# Karma doesn't find custom typing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to setup a test for a component that use a third JS library. This library has some typings and in the project the scenario works smoothly. When I try to run the standard stand in Karma it does trigger an error:

> *typing_name* is not defined

My project structure (simplified) is like this:

```
package.json
angular.json
karma.conf.js
all tsconfig files
typings/
    *typing_name*.d.ts
app/
    - components/
        - map/
            map.component.ts
            ...
            map.component.spec.ts
...
```

I've added my typings as following:

`ts.config.spec.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "app/test.ts",
    "app/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "typings/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "typings/*.d.ts",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

In the `map.component.ts` I use those definitions like this:

```
import { Something, SomethingElse, AnotherThing, ...} from 'my-custom-typing';
```

The test, since is very basic, it's just this:

```
describe('NngMapComponent', () => {
    let component: NngMapComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NngMapComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [ToastrService, TranslationService, DataService, ShareService],
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                ToastrModule.forRoot({
                    preventDuplicates: true
                }),
            ],
            declarations: [NngMapComponent]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NngMapComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    fit('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

running the test will result in this error:

> ReferenceError: *typing_name*is not defined

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you need to specify the `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
     "typeRoots": [
      "typings/*.d.ts", // this right here
    ],
  },
  "files": [
    "app/test.ts",
    "app/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    // "typings/*.d.ts" => Remove this, I don't think it's needed.
  ]
}
```

Try that. I am concerned that `types` and `typeRoots` properties might conflict but you can tinker.

Comment: Do you think maybe you have to add the that file to the `files` array in `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: Done, still nothing.